# How to use the value of a parameter as a property name in the return type for a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I've written a function to convert an object to an array where each element of the array contains the ID of the object. This currently works well with the following code:

```
const objectToArray = <T>(object: { [id: string]: T }): (T & { id: string })[] => {
  return Object.keys(object).map((key) => ({ id: key, ...object[key] }))
}
```

This will convert `{ a: { value: 1 }, b: { value: 2 } }` into `[{ id: 'a', value: 1 }, { id: 'b', value: 2 }]`.

What I would like to do is to take a second parameter `idField` which is the name of the field of the object to use as the ID field in the returned objects. E.g. if `idField` has the value `userId` then the result would be `[{ userId: 'a', value: 1 }, { userId: 'b', value: 2 }]`.

I've accomplished this in the logic of the function, but I can't figure out what the return type should be:

```
export const objectToArray = <T>(object: { [id: string]: T }, idField: string): ???[] => {
  return Object.keys(object).map((key) => ({ [idField]: key, ...object[key] }))
}
```

I've tried putting the return type as `(T & { [idField]: string })[]` but I get the error `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complex since *values* (function parameters) are runtime while *types* are only compile time. There's nothing preventing you from passing a **non constant** string to `idField`, completely giving up on the type check you're asking for here.

However, you *can* get the type safety you're asking for *if you do pass constant strings to the function*.

Let's start with a basic example (in javascript - omitted types)-

```js
function foo(prop) {
    return {
        [prop]: 42
    };
}
```

Just a function, that takes a property name and uses it to return an object with that property. This is, in essence, what you show in your example right? How would you type this?

```
function foo<T extends string>(prop: T): Record<T, number> {
    return {
        [prop]: 42
    } as Record<T, number>;
}
```

Try it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdESoAnGMAcwD4AKGIgMRmwBsiAuRDAJR8AStghxKRTABpEYEAFsARtkr1EAbwBQiXYkrYoISkm17ziANot2XIgF0+AVh16AvogCGZUeMky5RRU1AG4tNy0tTkNyRABeZFRGAHIQElUAOU8FbGSBMMQAekLEAD1EAAs4ADdVStVsSJIAOjTM7OwQopLPTk5EWlQiLRa4KArVAAVKOAAHLuK5OAG4LSA)

How does this work? We first make sure `prop` is a type that extends string (you can also be general and do `T extends string | number | symbol`) - since that is the type you need to use `prop` as a *property*.

Then we use this type to create the return type `Record<T, number>`. This is the same as-

```
{
    [k in T]: number
}
```

You can use either/or.

That assertion, however, is required. Since typescript cannot force the parameter to be a compile time constant all the time.

This will type check properly with strings known at compile time-

```
let s = foo('userName');
 // ^ Record<'userName', number>

s.userName; // all good
s.otherProp; // Property 'otherProp' does not exist on type 'Record<"userName", number>'
```

Ok, now let's use this for your function-

```
export const objectToArray = <T, K extends string>(
    object: { [id: string]: T },
    idField: K
): (T & Record<K, string>)[] => {
    return Object.keys(object).map(key => ({ [idField]: key, ...object[key] })) as (T & Record<K, string>)[];
};
```

Note that I assume `K` (the type of `idField`) is going to be a string, once again - you can use `K extends string | number | symbol` or any combination of those depending on your usecase. I'm also assuming the value of the property with `K` is `string`, hence `Record<K, string>`

Try it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)